# OpenGL - Set frame buffer texture to fully transparent

Tags: c++, opengl, framebuffer

I'm trying to render some text, but at the moment I'm rendering each glyph separately, which is slow and ineffective.

Therefore I want to change the system, so the text is just rendered into a separate texture **once**, whenever it changes, and then that texture should be rendered onscreen in the main render pass.

So far so good, the problem is, to draw it over the main scene, I only have two options. I could specify a specific color (e.g. green) as 'transparent', clear the frame buffer texture of the text with that color, draw the text and use a shader afterwards to render the result onto the main scene, minus the transparent color.

While that would work, I wouldn't be able to use that color for the actual text anymore.

Instead I'd much rather clear the alpha of the frame buffer texture entirely (to get a colorless, blank slate essentially) and then draw the text, but that doesn't seem to be possible?

```
glColorMask(GL_FALSE,GL_FALSE,GL_FALSE,GL_TRUE);
glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Doing this will just apply the specified rgb values with the alpha as 'intensity' of those colors. In this case it wouldn't do anything at all because the color components are disabled. But I need to change the **existing** alpha of the texture in the frame buffer, without using glDrawPixels (which is too slow).

Now, I could of course write an additional shader to set the alpha-value for each fragment to 0, but that doesn't seem as effective / fast.

What's the best way to handle something like this?

Comment: Why do you need to clear the alpha at all? If the glyphs have transparency, then you should have their transparency values written to the text FBO.

Answer (score 0):

> So far so good, the problem is, to draw it over the main scene, I only have two options. I could specify a specific color (e.g. green) as 'transparent', clear the frame buffer texture of the text with that color, draw the text and use a shader afterwards to render the result onto the main scene, minus the transparent color.

You're overcomplicating the whole thing. If you render your text/glyphs into a texture that has just a single channel that's being used as alpha channel, that gives you the glphys shape. The color is controlled in form of a vertex attribute and combined with the alpha from the texture upon rendering.

If you want to get fancy, instead of rendering the bare glyphs to the texture, you might instead want to produce a signed distance field map, to save on texture size, while retaining high quality text output.